# building prototype of a database in C++

Tags: c++, database, pointers, iterator

I'm trying to build prototype of a small database. First to put some integers as data and their conditions as visited or not. The conditions are initially set in the time of iterating the data set. I will change some of the conditions later on (not inside the code).

### Later to check the conditions using a function named 'isVisited' The code is following -

```
main.cpp
--------

#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include "Data.h"

using namespace std;

int main ()

{

    list<Data>* test = new list<Data>();

    test->push_back(12);
    test->push_back(13);
    test->push_back(14);

    for (list<Data>:: iterator it = test->begin(); it != test->end(); it++){

        it->visited_data = false;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
Data.h
------

#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H

class Data
{
public:

    Data();
    void isVisited(Data* data_);
    bool visited_data;
};

#endif
```

---

```
Data.cpp
--------


#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include "Data.h"
using namespace std;

Data::Data()
{

}

void Data::isVisited(Data* data_)
{
    Data* _data = data_;

    if (_data->isVisited){

        cout<<"this data is visited"<<endl;
    }

    else
        cout<<"this data is not visited"<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: how to fix the errors ?

Comment: @Chad In german we have a saying: _It's like pulling out whirms from s.ones nose ..._

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to post.ERROR: C:\C++ programe file\test2\main.cpp|13|error: no matching function for call to 'std::list<Data>::push_back(int)'|

Comment: I though that you are very experienced so the errors are obvious to you.

Comment: @Arefe LOL! May be I'm experienced, but way off from a human c++ compiler!!

Comment: The push_back function works for list. Probably, the inserted integers need to cast as Data type. I tried but didn't work out that.

Comment: Correct, you have provided no way to construct `Data` from `int`.  As a side note, there is absolutely no reason to dynamically allocate `test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a container that is expecting `Data`, but you are providing it `int`.  You need some type of conversion operator.  The simplest way is to provide an implicit constructor for `Data` that takes `int`.

```
class Data
{
public:
   Data(int)
   {
      // this should do something "appropriate"
   }
};
```

However, from the code you've posted so far it's not entirely clear how you expect to handle the integers you are passing into the data set (`test`) as currently you have no storage for values held in your data set, only a flag to indicate whether or not it's been visited.

On a side note, `std::list` is rarely the most appropriate data structure to use, especially if you are planning on interacting with it via `push_back()` only as in your example.  For this case, prefer `std::vector`.

On a further side note, your `test` object is leaking.  There is no valid reason to have dynamically allocated it anyway, so I will present you with some alternatives.

The most preferred way would be to create it with automatic storage duration, like this:

```
std::vector<Data> test;
test.push_back(12);
// ...
```

If you feel you must dynamically allocate it, you should wrap it in a smart pointer.

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<Data>> test(new std::vector<Data>);
test->push_back(12);
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks, its working now. Is there another way to convert from int to Data without constructor ?

Comment: There are a multitude of ways to accomplish that, however without knowing how `Data` is supposed to interact with the `int` values provided, it's hard to say what an appropriate way is.